# How to Implement Microsoft Graph API using Java and Maven

Tags: java, azure, maven, microsoft-graph-api

I want to Implement Microsoft Graph API for sending an email.

For that, I have referred the code from https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-java-connect-sample.

But, The code present here is in Gradle format. I need it in Maven format.

What I Want to do is :

1. Get The access token from GraphAPI
2. Using This Access token Call the Send Mail API of GraphAPI

I have perfrom above two functionality using postman.

same I want to implement using Java & Maven

Please let me know if any sample available for this functionality using Maven

Comment: What functionality exactly? Please add the description of what you have and what you try to achieve to the question.

Comment: @JFMeier I have Updated the question as per knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven and Gradle are just build tools. You can use that sample, just need to create a `pom.xml` file with dependencies used in `build.gradle` file. I have done that for you.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test2</groupId>
    <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gilecode.yagson</groupId>
        <artifactId>j9-reflection-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Download that sample and delete all the files except src folder, put the pom.xml together with src folder. A maven project has done.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.BTW do you have any idea how can we get authorization [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290670/incorrect-redirect-url-address-while-working-with-microsoft-graph-api)

Comment: @E_FreeLancer added the answer there.