# Incorrect redirect URL address while working with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I am working on Microsoft graph API for implementing the Email functionality.

- The source code is referred from the official **[microsoftgraph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-java-connect-sample)** github account.
- I am following the step mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-java-connect-sample#integrate-the-microsoft-graph-api-into-a-java-command-line-app-using-username-and-password)
- On [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-java-connect-sample#integrate-the-microsoft-graph-api-into-a-java-command-line-app-using-username-and-password) Step I supposed to get a `code` in redirect URL address.

I suppose to get below url as mentioned in the steps.

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient?code={IAQABAAIAAABHh4kmS_aKT5XrjzxRAtHz5S...p7OoAFPmGPqIq-1_bMCAA}&session_state=dd64ce71-4424-494b-8818-be9a99ca0798`

instead of that I am getting below url

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/a1f1e214-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx59641/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxx-1xxxx-xxxx-ad2a-d80d3f51638a&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient&scope=Files.ReadWrite%20openid%20User.Read%20Mail.Send%20Mail.ReadWrite`

Note: The Above step is highligted in the [documentation](https://login.microsoftonline.com/a1f1e214-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx59641/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxx-1xxxx-xxxx-ad2a-d80d3f51638a&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient&scope=Files.ReadWrite%20openid%20User.Read%20Mail.Send%20Mail.ReadWrite)

**Is this because I dont have check the box checked next to oauth2/nativeclient which is mention at Step 4 [Point 8](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/console-java-connect-sample#step-4-register-the-console-java-connect-app) in the documentation.**

Any guidance will be great help

Comment: Redirect Uri should be same as that you have specified on azure portal

Comment: yes I have tried that. But I am not getting any access code I have mention in my question

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: @CaiyiJu : I am still not getting the url that you have mention in your answer (The url wich contains the code) instead the URL which I am getting contains `code&client_id=`.

Comment: @E_FreeLancer Have you entered your user name and password to authenticate?

Comment: @CaiyiJu :Yes, After that it redirecting to the url that I have mentioned.

Comment: @E_FreeLancer That doesn't make sense, you signed in successfully and redirect to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/a1f1e214-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx59641/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`?

Comment: @E_FreeLancer You should be redirect to this endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient ` which configured in azure portal and constants.java class

Comment: @E_FreeLancer Any update for this issue?

Comment: @TonyJu : No, Still no progress on this one. Now I am trying to implement this using JavaScript. My Final goal is to implement the E-Mail functionality using OpenGraph API

Comment: @TonyJu : No, Still no progress on this one. Now I am trying to implement this using JavaScript. My Final goal is to implement the E-Mail functionality using OpenGraph API

Answer (score 1):

> The command line interface opens a browser window on the Azure Active
>   Directory authorization endpoint. Enter your user name and password to
>   authenticate. When you are authenticated, you're taken to an
>   authorization window for the sample app. Review and accept the scopes
>   requested by the sample app. Click the Ok button on the authorization
>   window.

When you got that url, you should be asked to login. After that, you will get the code.

**The steps:**

Register an app on Azure portal->get the client id-> go to Constants.java class and replace the client_id with yours.

[image]

Run the PublicClient class.

[image]

Login in with your account, then you will get the code.

[image]